# Function Call using Background Worker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am having a single function InitializeList(). Now, this function I am calling from three Background worker's DoWork Event.
So, does the calling of a single function from multiple Backgroundworker run parallel? 
Or I have to create three different functions & pass them in different Background workers to run in parallel?

For additional information, this single function does use an update of different controls on the windows form.

```
private void InitializeList()
    {
        try
        {
            _testMaster1 = new TestMasters();
            string query = string.Empty;
            query = "SELECT TestMasterFVT01.* FROM TestMasterFVT01 WHERE ((TestMasterFVT01.ThreadNO)<>0) ORDER BY TestMasterFVT01.TestID, TestMasterFVT01.SubTestID;";

            _testMaster1 = Singleton.Instance.GetData(query);
            mainListView1.Items.Clear();
            mainListView1.Items.AddRange(Singleton.Instance.ListViewItemCollection.ToArray());

            _itemCount1 = _testMaster1.Count;

            if (_itemCount1 == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please check Model Setting");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            textBoxBoardName1.Select();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check Model Setting");
            Environment.Exit(0);
            Logger.Error(ex);
        }
    }


void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
InitializeList();
}

void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
InitializeList();
}

void backgroundWorker3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
InitializeList();
}
```

Comment: Share us the code you had or you plan to implement.

Comment: I am planning to implement three Background workers. In which DoWork  I am planning to call single function. But I need these three Background workers to run in parallel.

Comment: You can't update controls from DoWork(), an InvalidOperationException should remind you about that.  Updating UI must be done with the ProgressChanged or RunWorkerCompleted events.  BGW ensures those events are fired on the UI thread.  Necessarily their code cannot run concurrently since it is only one thread.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you for the information. Now if I exclude the part of UI then will my single function run parallelly from three background workers?

Comment: The DoWork event handlers *can* run concurrently.  No guarantee they will.  Do pause a bit at running multiple threads and not knowing enough about threading yet.  The ideal number of BGWs to use when you are just starting out learning about them is one.

Answer (score -1):

Calling of a single function from multiple Backgroundworker run parallel. And if this single function does use an update of different controls on the windows form, you can call the function from three Background workers